# Compress Raw buffer data of video (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, video, compression

I have raw buffer video data which I need to stream over the net as and when requested by the clients. This data is very huge. So I will need to compress and save it at my server location.
One way I understand of doing this convert the data into a video file ".avi" and save it and then stream it frame by frame as and when requested.
I have used the VideoWriter function of OpenCV for converting the buffer to mat and then to ".avi" file with MPEG4 encoding.

However I want to know if there is any way I can compress the raw buffer data and save it in a file. Can anyone suggest me if this is possible?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you need non-destructive compression? Then using e.g. LZ compression works. But normally, one uses destructive compression for video and images, e.g. MPEG4/Fourier-based methods. (One part of MPEG4 and also jpeg is discrete cosine transform).

Comment: Afaik ffmpeg and avconv can handle raw video data

Comment: Thanks for the reply? Can you elaborate a bit or give me some link where I can read about these methods?